# Is it possible to disable the right click and close all on messagebox ctype python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, messagebox, right-click, ctype

I have a piece of code showing a messagebox implemented using ctype lib in python.
My question is there a way to cancel the close all or right click when creating multiple ctype messagebox?

```
def msgbox(self,hwnd,msg,thid,pid):
        MB_OK = 0x0
        MB_OKCXL = 0x01
        MB_YESNOCXL = 0x03
        MB_YESNO = 0x04
        MB_HELP = 0x4000
        ICON_EXLAIM=0x30
        ICON_INFO = 0x40
        ICON_STOP = 0x10
        MB_TOPMOST=0x40000
        MB_SYSTEMMODAL=0x1000
        """
                HEX VALUE LINK
        https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MsgBox.htm
        """
        writeLogs = WriteLogs(
                    pathLog = app_config['path_logs'] +"\\"+strftime("%Y_%m_%d")+".log",
                    timedate = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
                    )
        writeLogs.appendLogA(msg)
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(hwnd, msg+str(operatorMessage), "[Error]", MB_OK | ICON_STOP | MB_SYSTEMMODAL)
```

[image]

Comment: It's not a ctype messagebox. `ctypes` is the interface to libraries with a C API. The library you're using is `user32.dll` which is offered by Microsoft. This is their [documentation for `MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: hi sir do you have sample code to try with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `win32con.WM_CLOSE` to close a message box:

```
import win32con
ctypes.windll.user32.PostMessageA(hwnd, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)
```

To disable the right click on taskbar you can attach you messagebox to a window with no icon so it will be invisible on taskbar (No right click).

```
import ctypes
import win32con
import win32gui


style = win32con.MB_OK


wc = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
wc.lpszClassName = "TaskbarDemo"
rclass = win32gui.RegisterClass(wc)

hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow(rclass, "Taskbar Demo", style, \
                0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                0, 0, None, None)


MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
MessageBox(hwnd, 'Message', 'Window title', 0)
```

**EDIT:**

```
def main(name):
    try:
       ...        
       wc.lpszClassName = name
       ...
```

Call it with:

```
main("TaskbarDemo")
main("zefaz")
...
```

and so on...

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for your great suggestion..but what is the difference when i use ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowA(None, "[Error]").

I came a conclusion when creating a new messagebox thread i get there hwnd = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowA(None, "[Error]") and I add to list

then by using 

for h in list:
   ctypes.windll.user32.PostMessageA(hwnd, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)

Comment: Hi sir let be clear, the objective of what i'm trying to do is to stop the user to right click + close all the generated error boxes. Thanks

Comment: you have sample on how to achieve the blocking/disallow of right click for them not ot close all the message boxes?

Comment: @iamcoder you did not mention where to disable the right click, you should specify it.

Comment: i add a capture image..please check.@WoLy

Comment: I edit the post, and try some code. but it has an error..@WoLy

Comment: @iamcoder Your edit was rejected by some users, but i took a look then i realize that you  are using the same class name.To resolve the problem call `main()` with different class names.Check my edit

Comment: hi sir..yup i actually done that...when i create a "thread" i get the thread-id then input to class name..but my doubt on that solution is that it may slow down the computer if multiple occurrence because of multiple registerclass????? thanks for the help..